# Why does ST_Transform fail when transforming to 4326?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, coordinate-transformation

I have a postgis table with some data which looks like this:

| distance | id | nr | X | Y | description | strecke | point | gsal_strecke | rikz | gsal_km_anf_p | gsal_km_end_p | gsal_geo_compound | rk | kilometer | basepoint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.088918198132633 | 9105 | 1 | 7.59833269418573 | 50.3171094720011 | valide with result | 3507 | POINT (3400245.168425543 5576618.697108934) | 3507 | 2.0 | 123905.310 | 123945.537 | LINESTRING (3400253.52199817 5576605.02429315, 3400251.48999817 5576609.59229315, 3400247.37399817 5576618.87129315, 3400243.28599817 5576628.16129316, 3400239.24399817 5576637.47229316, 3400237.27599817 5576642.06929316) | 1 | 123.92110139140328 | POINT (3400247.0804134225 5576619.538465925) |
| 4.601389947759623 | 9106 | 611171 | 8.83478109 | 54.7923646 | crash | 1201 | POINT (3489442.4653895213 6073687.653162317) | 1201 | 0.0 | 162291.691 | 162329.922 | LINESTRING (3489446.77287361 6073662.83069441, 3489447.226 6073701.05844041) | 1 | 162.31646103819043 | POINT (3489447.066456252 6073687.598624319) |

This table holds the end result of some calculations. In short what happens is, that a collection of points is inserted into the database and if they are within a certain perimter of a given rail, a basepoint to that rail is calculated. This calculation takes place in SRID 5683
The data is fetched by a Service, which returns them as geojson. According to the [specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-4), geoJSON works best when used with WGS84 coordinates.
So when fetching the data, I have to transform the coordinates.

The query I use looks like this:

```
select *, ST_X(ST_Transform(point, 4326)) as x, ST_Y(ST_Transform(point, 4326)) as y from bp40.bp40_punktlage;
```

The first of these two example rows yields the following result:

| distance | id | nr | X | Y | Objektbezeichnung | strecke | punkt | gsal_strecke | rikz | gsal_km_anf_p | gsal_km_end_p | gsal_geo_compound | rk | kilometer | fusspunkt | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.088918198132633 | 9105 | 1 | 7.59833269418573 | 50.3171094720011 | valide mit ergebnis | 3507 | POINT (3400245.168425543 5576618.697108934) | 3507 | 2.0 | 123905.310 | 123945.537 | LINESTRING (3400253.52199817 5576605.02429315, 3400251.48999817 5576609.59229315, 3400247.37399817 5576618.87129315, 3400243.28599817 5576628.16129316, 3400239.24399817 5576637.47229316, 3400237.27599817 5576642.06929316) | 1 | 123.92110139140328 | POINT (3400247.0804134225 5576619.538465925) | 7.598332691520598 | 50.317109473199004 |

Now for some reason I cannot explain, the second row just crashes yielding the follow error message:

**SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: transform: Invalid argument (22)**
According to the [postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/errcodes-appendix.html)

This is a internal error, which does not really help me understand what is wrong here.

I have checked the geometry for validity (st_isvalid) and both rows contain valid geometry.
Also the initial X,Y coordinates are valid and pinpoint the location I want them to be in.

**EDIT 1**
Out of curiosity i tried the following queries:

```
select st_transform(point,5682) from bp40_punktlage
--works just fine with both rows

select st_transform(st_transform(punkt, 5682),4326) from bp40_punktlage
-- crashes with the same error
```

PostgreSQL 13.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
Postgis Version : 3.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

**Edit 2**
As requestet here is the CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE bp40.bp40_punktlage (
    distance float8 NULL,
    id int4 NULL,
    nr varchar NULL,
    "X" float8 NULL,
    "Y" float8 NULL,
    "description" varchar NULL,
    strecke varchar NULL,
    point geometry NULL,
    gsal_strecke varchar(4) NULL,
    rikz float8 NULL,
    gsal_km_anf_p numeric(19, 3) NULL,
    gsal_km_end_p numeric(19, 3) NULL,
    gsal_geo_compound geometry NULL,
    rk int8 NULL,
    kilometer float8 NULL,
    basepoint geometry NULL
);
```

Inserts are a bit more complicated, since the data goes through several tables and processing steps until it arrives at the table shown in this post. I will try to add them over the course of the day.

**Edit 3**
The geometries are valid.
st_srid() return 5863 for both points, as expected. I tried transforming them into 5862 just for the sake of trying. But it fails when transforming to 4326, no matter from which SRID i start

Comment: I tried to reproduce this error in many postgres and postgis versions... all of them worked fine. Check this **[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8f0584a6882c43afaee7213b8e09ae5b)**. Could you share the create table and insert statements? It might shed some light ..

Comment: Have you tried using `ST_MakeValid`?: See last query in this **[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c22e7b339d095d7468eca96355774b5e)**

Comment: Could it be that postgis does not know what the initial coordinate system is? What happens if you try this? select st_transform(st_setsrid(punkt, 5682),4326)